# java keystore with multiple aliases on apache

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, keystore

A [JKS file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) (Java key store), May contains many aliases, this means it may hold many private+public keys combinations, some aliases may be trusted, some not.

When I define jetty to use SSL, [as this guide mention](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html) ,
I dont set alias. So what happens when there are multiple aliases in the same keystore ?
What aliases is chosen by default ? Because some of them may be trusted, and some of the aliases may not be trusted (and show warning to end-user in the browser).

Thanks

Comment: By apache do you mean Apache httpd?

Comment: Actually i mean jetty 9 (solrcloud)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008837/configure-ssl-on-jetty

Answer (score 1):

Apache's webserver does not support JKS files directly, you will have to export it's public and private key to to PEM formatted files and explicitly list them per virtual host. This is a one to one so you don't have to worry about what the alias is.

See the [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) for more information.